# CRM365 - Views with complex column layout

Tags: layout, view, dynamics-crm, crm

The current CRM UI allows you to create relatively complex queries which you can even extend further with tools like FetchXML Builder.

However, when we get to select the columns in the View layout, the interface provides access only to the first direct related set of entities and does not navigate further down.

There are many cases where the column you want to include in the View is just "two-clicks" away and you cannot include it because is "too far". To make things worse, the FetchXML Builder allows you to re-write the join but it does not allow you change the the columns layout you started with when you opened the View initially. IOW, you can modify the query logic but you cannot include additional columns as required.

One possible solution would be to edit the solution directly and inject the FetchXML directly (I have not tried this though) but I would like to listen to the community opinion first or to other possible solution.

Regards and thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a long existing limitation. There is no supported customization workaround to circumvent this other than building a Fetchxml report or Power BI report to embed with the necessary layout.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/choose-and-configure-columns#add-columns):

> You can include columns from the current entity or any of the related entities that have a 1:N entity relationship with the current entity.

You can [tweak the `layoutxml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/customize-dev/customize-entity-views#create-views) of any view, but still it has to be in supported zone to avoid failures.

Comment: Thank you Arun. I wonder when Microsoft plans to fix this issue.

Comment: @Maf, you can submit an idea, we can gather community support and see what MS PG team says about it :)